# Laravel 5.8 redirected you too many times, middleware problem

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-5.8

I have a signup route. After it register on step1, it emails to the user to verify his account and have a link on his email. After clicking the link, it should redirect to `signup/step2`, and finished and he can access the `job-seeker/home`.

so the logic is after finished the registration, user cannot visit again to `signup/step2` cause user already finished fill up the form.
and before fillup `signup/step2`, he can't access also the `job-seeker/home`. So it's vice versa.

basically my middleware was first: check if the user completed the step2 and added true on column `is_completed` in database. then on the second middleware is to visit only his route by his role, he can't access other routes from other role and redirect to his home based on his role.

But it throws me too many redirect and switching both side even I still didn't fill up the step2 yet. this is my gif below.

[image]

---

**MyCode**

***Kernel.php***

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    ...
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'isCompleted' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsCompleted::class,
    ];
```

***Middleware/IsCompleted.php***

```
class IsCompleted
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->user()->isCompleted == 1){
            return $next($request);
        }

        // if 0, redirect to step2
        return redirect()->route('register.step2');
    }
```

***Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php***

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            if ( Auth::user()->hasRole('job-seeker') ) {
                return redirect()->route('job-seeker.home');
            } else if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.home');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
```

***Routes/Web.php***

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['verified', 'isCompleted']], function() {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'name' => 'admin.'], function() {
        Route::get('/home', function(){ return "test"; })->name('admin.home');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'job-seeker', 'name' => 'job-seeker.'], function() {
        Route::get('/home',         'Jobseeker\HomeController@index')->name('job-seeker.home');
    });
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true, 'register' => false]);
Route::get('signup/{usertype}'      , 'Auth\RegisterController@getStep1')->name('register.step1');
Route::post('signup/{usertype}'     , 'Auth\RegisterController@postStep1');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('signup/step2'       , 'Auth\RegisterController@getStep2')->name('register.step2');
    Route::post('signup/step2'      , 'Auth\RegisterController@postStep2');
});
```

---

**EDIT 1**

I inspect the page and go to network tab, and this is the result.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? It should not be too hard to check why any of these redirects occur

Comment: it shows me too many redirect, and switching both side even I still didn't fill up the step2

Comment: @StormSpirit inspect the page and go to network tab (dont forget to check "preserve log) to debug exactly what's happening.
and can you post your App\Http\kernel.php too

Comment: I added Edit one

Comment: basically my middleware was first: check if the user completed the step2 and added true on column `is_completed` in database. then on the second middleware is to visit only his route by his role, he can't access other routes from other role and redirect to his home based on his role.

Answer (score 0):

your `RedirectIfAuthenticated` keeps redirecting all the time. It doesn't ever get to `$next($request)` for Authenticated User.

You need to have some logic like

```
if (route is seeker.home and user can visit seeker.home) {
    return $next(request);
}
```

instead of

```
return redirect()->route('job-seeker.home');
```

Comment: basically this middleware to check his role and redirect to home based on his role, if he visit other route from other role, he redirect to his home. and the other middleware was first to check if he completed the full registration, and can access all the sites based on his role. I don't know if I am doing right on my logic

Comment: You're never allowing the request to pass. Even if user CAN access the route, you still call `return redirect()->route('job-seeker.home');` instead of calling `return $next($request)`. So he gets redirected back to the same route...and then redirected again, and redirected again, thus `Too many redirects`